# UIPicker View in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uipickerview, picker

I've searched around the web and haven't found yet a good example or reference for utilizing an UIPicker View on Xamarin 5.10/iOS 7+.

If someone can point me on the right direction how to bring up a picker view when the user touches a button, show me how I'll be able to access the item the user selected and how to include a done button to hide/close the UIPicker view I will be eternally grateful.

I think I've spent a lot of time on this and have found examples but they're really super bare bones and don't explain anything.

Thanks again!

Comment: Take a look at my answer in the above dup and see if that gets you started in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also use [PickerCells](https://github.com/newky2k/PickerCells) which supports the nice functionality you'll see in apps like iOS Calendar etc. I.e. the picker view becomes "collapsible".

It's available on GitHub as per my link above, but also NuGet (as dhpickercells). While not updated that frequently, it still fine under iOS 8.x and 9.x.

See screenshot below:

[image]